# How Magento 2.2.2 creditmemo create and save functionality work

Tags: magento2.2.2, creditmemo

While working on custom creditmemo functionalities, I created this flow diagram to show a high level view, how Magento 2.2.2 performs creditmemo create/save operation from admin area.

[image: Magento 2.2.2 credit memo create save functionality]

Comment: Why is this still saying [on hold]? I have updated the post description though.

Comment: thanks for this contribution! it was quite convoluted and your answer cleared it up.